# Understanding Contexts in Javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm struggling to understand how contexts work in JavaScript or specifically deriving the value of **this**. in my case i have Person constructor that returns an object. From my understanding the value of this depends on the way that the function is called. For instance calling the person function like this "**Person()**" .the value returned for **this** will be the window. How do i then ensure that the person values passed are exactly what is returned

```js
function Person(personName,Title,Phone,Email,Id, picUrl, description){
     var myusername = this.username;
    var myTitle = this.Title;
    var myPhone = this.Phone;
    var myEmail = this.Email;
    var myId = this.Id;
    var mypicUrl = this.picUrl;
    var mydescription = this.description;

    return {
        name: myusername,
        Title: myTitle,
        phoneNumber: myPhone,
        Email: myEmail,
        UserId: myId,
        PictureUrl: mypicUrl,
        Description: mydescription
    }

}

function getallDetails (){

var PeopleCompleteList = [];
for (i=0; i< data.d.results.length; i++) {                           
    if(data.d.results[i]['Name'] != null){
      personName = data.d.results[i]['Name'].Name.split('|')[2];
      userName = data.d.results[i]['Name']['Name'];
      UserTitle = data.d.results[i]['Name']['Title'];
      UserphoneNumber = data.d.results[i]['Name']['WorkPhone'];
      UserEmail = data.d.results[i]['Name']['EMail'];
      Id = data.d.results[i]['Name']['Id'];
      picUrl= WebURL + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&accountname='+UserEmail;
      description = data.d.results[i]['pozb'];
      PeopleCompleteList.push(Person(personName, UserTitle, UserphoneNumber,UserEmail,Id, picUrl, description));
    
      }
         
    }
   }//end function
```

Comment: I don’t see what sense using `this` like you are doing here would make to begin with. You don’t need `this` to access _parameters_, and neither do you need to “copy” them into differently named local variables first.

Comment: You don't have a constructor, you have a method called `Person` that you are also using as a method. A constructor would be called with `new` and will not return anything, but will just set the values on the `this` context. And I agree with @CBroe you seem to misunderstand completely what are arguments, how to handle them. A constructor will also generally not give anything back (if it does return anymore than a primitive value, it will no longer be a constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CBroe and @Icepickle said in comments, you are not using the Person function as a constructor. You need to call your method with the `new` keyword. By doing so :

- the `this` keyword inside your function will be a reference to the object you're willing to create (otherwise it would be a reference to the global object)
- the function doesn't need to return anything as it implicitly returns the object referenced by `this`

I'd advise you read this article : [MDN - the new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

Meanwhile, the snippet below shows what your code would look like if you used the Person function as a constructor

```js
function Person(personName, title, phone, email, id, picUrl, description) {
   // populating the object behind the 'this' reference with each argument
   // if you call this method with the 'new' keyword, 'this' will be a reference to the instance you are creating
   
   this.username = personName;
   this.title = title;
   this.phoneNumber = phone;
   this.email = email;
   this.userId = Id;
   this.pictureUrl = picUrl;
   this.description = description;

   // if this function is called with the 'new' keyword, you don't have to return anything. the reference behind 'this' will be implicitly returned 
}

function getallDetails() {
  // local variable declarations are usually put on top of the function 
  var peopleCompleteList = [], personName, userName, userTitle, userphoneNumber, userEmail, id, picUrl, description;
  for (i=0; i< data.d.results.length; i++) {                           
    if (data.d.results[i]['Name'] != null) {
      personName = data.d.results[i]['Name'].Name.split('|')[2];
      userName = data.d.results[i]['Name']['Name'];
      userTitle = data.d.results[i]['Name']['Title'];
      userphoneNumber = data.d.results[i]['Name']['WorkPhone'];
      userEmail = data.d.results[i]['Name']['EMail'];
      id = data.d.results[i]['Name']['Id'];
      picUrl= WebURL + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&accountname='+UserEmail;
      description = data.d.results[i]['pozb'];
      // adding the 'new' keyword before invoking the Person method 
      peopleCompleteList.push(new Person(personName, userTitle, userphoneNumber,userEmail,Id, picUrl, description));
      }
   }
}//end function
```

**Couple side notes :**

- You forgot to use the `var` keyword when declaring variables in the `getallDetails` function. It's a bad practice as they will all be global variables and won't be cleared after the execution of the `getallDetails` function
- Most of your variables declarations violate the [JavaScript variable naming convention](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp). I updated the snippet with proper variable names (using the camelCase notation).

Comment: Pitty you didn't point him to global vars he is creating and naming conventions in JavaScript, I think you could do a lot more explaining here

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, You can say context is the place where **this** reside. For example:

```
    <script> 
     function show() {
       this.context = 'sudhir';
     }
    </script>
```

This is equivalent to

```
    <script>
     var context;
     function show() {
       this.context = 'sudhir';
     }
   </script>
```

Both functions are written on the global scope. So, **this** refers to global means scope or your context is global. Now let's see the interesting example:

```
    <script>
      function newContext() {
        var a = function show() {
          this.context = 'sudhir';
        }
      }
    </script>
```

It's equivalent to write here like this:

```
   <script>     
     function newContext() {
       var context;
       var a = function show() {
          this.context = 'sudhir';
       }
     }
     </script>
```

Here **this** refers to the function show which is written on the scope of newContext function. Hence, Context of **this** is newContext.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you what I will have done.
First of all, if you create an object, you don't have to return a value.

```
function Person(personName,Title,Phone,Email,Id, picUrl, description){
    this.personName = personName;
    [...]
    this.mydescription = description;
}
```

Then you instantiate your "class" like :

```
var person = new Person('David', ..., 'some description');
```

And access attribute like that :

```
console.log('Person name is', person.personName);
```

JavaScript "This" is about function scope, example :

```
    function Person(personName,Title,Phone,Email,Id, picUrl, description){
        this.personName = personName;
        [...]
        this.mydescription = description;

        function someAnonymousFunction(){
           console.log('Person name is', this.personName); // Person name is Undefined
// Because this is a reference to someAnonymousFunction
        }
    }
```

Javascript trick to preserve this is to stock the context in variable :

```
function Person(personName,Title,Phone,Email,Id, picUrl, description){    
    var self = this;
    this.personName = personName;
    [...]
    this.mydescription = description;

    function someAnonymousFunction(){
         console.log('Person name is', self.personName); // Person name is David
         // Because we use self variable instead of this here
    }
}
```

**But you have an easier way**
ECMAScript 2015 includes classes syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

**If you care about navigator compatibility, you must use TypeScript**
https://www.typescriptlang.org/
Typescript allow you to write more readable JavaScript code, especially about classes. Then, you can "compile" your code in JavaScript by choosing with version of JavaScript you want in output files.

Hope it helps,

Mickael

Comment: i really appreciate all your comments..they have given me better understanding around contexts, variable declaration and generally writing better code.